# Price filter in cart system for products

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to use this code for filtering the price change in ajax below is my model in which i set a query for filtering the data but results are not showing here... & Ajax request is running in every slider of price..

> Failing in where condition what is $min & $max;

```
  function _priceSlider(){
    $min = $_POST['min'];
    $max = $_POST['max'];

    $array = $this->db->get_where('product',"new_price BETWEEN $min AND $max")->result();
    $this->load->view('front/temp/priceSlider', compact('array'));}
```

**Here is my Ajax Request**

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 500,
    max: 100000,
    values: [ 500, 100000 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

        var data = {};
        data.min = ui.values[0];
        data.max = ui.values[1];
        data.action = "_frontEvent";
        data.method = "priceSlider";
        $('#range').text(data.min+' - ' + data.max);
        sendData(ajaxReq , data).done(function(c){
            console.log(c);
            $(".sortdiv").html(c);
            });
        }
    });
```

**Here is my Slider input values**

```
            <div class="widget price mb-50">
                   <!-- Widget Title -->
                <h6 class="widget-title mb-30">Filter by</h6>
                  <!-- Widget Title 2 -->
                   <p class="widget-title2 mb-30">Price</p>
                     <div class="widget-desc">
                            <div class="slider-range">
                                <div id="slider"></div><br>
                                <span id="range">Range: Rs/500 - Rs/100000</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting  $min and $max values in _priceSlider function ?

Comment: Yes i'm getting the values but in condition they are not responding and not fetching the data from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution to fix it
here it is:

```
$this->db->where('new_price BETWEEN $min And $max');
$this->db->get('product')->result();
```